# select top value from multiple values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, subquery

I have this table

**trans**

```
id
user_id
amt
desc
bal
created
```

**sample data is**

```
id  user_id desc    amt     bal     created
1   1   credit  12.00   12.00   2013-07-02 00:00:00
2   1   credit  44.00   56.00   2013-07-09 00:00:00
3   1   debit   11.00   45.00   2013-07-18 00:00:00
4   2   credit  11.00   11.00   2013-07-12 01:17:08
5   2   credit  45.00   56.00   2013-07-13 01:17:08
6   2   debit   15.00   41.00   2013-07-14 01:17:08
7   3   credit  33.00   33.00   2013-07-15 01:17:52
8   3   credit  45.00   78.00   2013-07-16 01:17:52
9   3   debit   25.00   53.00   2013-07-17 01:17:52
```

now i need to select the current balance from each user only,  so outout should be
**output**
    id  user_id desc    amt bal created
    3   1   debit   11.00   45.00   2013-07-18 00:00:00
    6   2   debit   15.00   41.00   2013-07-12 01:17:08
    9   3   credit  25.00   53.00   2013-07-12 01:17:52

this is what i tried

```
SELECT * 
FROM trans
WHERE created
IN (

SELECT MAX( created ) 
FROM trans
GROUP BY user_id
)
```

this gives two records for each user instead of 1 each. what am i doing wrong?

The goal is the select **Top amounts (highest and descending)**

it is ok if two dates and time are same, but not returning two records each

Comment: You're selecting from trans without a `GROUP BY` in the outer `SELECT`.

Comment: So now you do not want the balance but rather the largest deposit? You seem to be working on something that involves money... You need to think about this if this is more than a toy project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find this simpler if you use a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM trans t
   INNER JOIN (
       SELECT Max(Id) MaxId
       FROM trans
       GROUP BY User_Id
   ) t2 ON t.Id = t2.MaxId
```

This assumes the `MAX(Id)` is the max record you're looking for with each user (and is unique).  If not, you can use `MAX(created)` with the `User_Id` the same way, but it could yield multiple results per user if the time is the same.  For example:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM trans t
   INNER JOIN (
       SELECT Max(created) MaxCreated, User_Id
       FROM trans
       GROUP BY User_Id
   ) t2 ON t.User_Id = t2.User_Id AND t.Created = t2.MaxCreated
```

Comment: thank you very much, but i found that your solution simply select the latest trans, not the top trans value by amt. can you help me correct this

Answer (score 0):

A good solution is;

```
SELECT user_id, SUM(IF(desc='credit',-1,1)*amt) AS balance 
FROM trans GROUP BY user_id
```

Your suggested table is not well designed. You should really **not** store the *balance* for each row, as that can introduce inconsistency in your data. What happens if the individual `amt` don't agree with the `bal` fields? Store just the `amt` fields. It would be simpler if you dropped the `desc` column and stored credits as negative. In that case, you just select `SUM(amt) AS balance`.